# How to send a short Ajax request to PHP, get confirmation and don't wait for full processing to finish

Tags: php, ajax, fork

first post here :) 
I have a mobile app (Phonegap) that sends an ajax request to a PHP server, say a friend invite. When receiving the request, a few things have to be done (create links, authorisations, send e-mails, etc) which take a long time (5 sec). During that time, the user on the app is looking at a spinner, waiting for the ajax request to complete.

Ideally:

- return a confirmation "Friend request received", without waiting for the process to finish.
- No Cron jobs because waiting 1 min is too long.
- Something simple (Gearman is scary)

**On the app :**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.my_site.com/action.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: "my_guid="+my_guid+"&friend_guid="+friend_guid, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        // Send confirmation
    },
    error: function(json) {
        // Show error
    }
}
```

**On the server (PHP):**

```
$my_guid = $_POST['my_guid'];
$friend_guid = $_POST['friend_guid'];
// return here confirmation to the app
veryLongFunction($my_guid,$friend_guid); //continue executing long function
```

Comment: are you overthinking this or do I not understand? don't load the spinner for the ajax event and continue running your functions after you've fired the ajax event.

Comment: well, I need to be sure the data made it safe there. And if it did, I want to give control back to the user. So... until I get the confirmation that the data made it there without any error, the user should not be allowed to leave the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, don't show the spinner.

**It's asynchronous anyway**

Just don't show the spinner. The request itself is asynchronous. The user can continue using the page while the request is waiting in the background for a response. Only when the response is received, the success handler kicks in.

**Alternative feedback**

So instead of showing a spinner overlay, I'd show a small notification at the top of the page saying 'Saving....', something that doesn't block sight too much, maybe even just a small icon or animation in a corner, or on top of the button they clicked (see snippet below) to do the action.

Then, when the response is received show a more visible notification indicating success or error.

**Handling navigation**

Navigating away from the page would end the request. That doesn't mean that the PHP script is ended right away, but if you start outputting information and sending it to the client, your server will notice the connection is gone and it will kill the PHP script. You can prevent this and make PHP finish the request by using [ignore_user_abort(true)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php).

Minor detail: while the friend invite is being saved, you cannot really see that, so if you navigate to another page that also shows the friend invite button, it's tricky to make that show the right status. One solution might be to set a 'saving' flag as soon as you start saving the invite, but personally I wouldn't go that far. Just make sure you script gracefully handles a duplicate save and hide the collision from the user.

**Prototype of inline indicator**

Here is a small snippet to show what I mean by showing it inline. It doesn't do an actual request, but simulates it using `setTimeout`. You can click each button and you can continue using the page. Instead of showing a big spinner, I just show a text in the button you just clicked, so you know which friend request you are saving.

So this way, there is more feedback to the user (the exact name that is saving), the feedback is less obtrusive (it's only there in the place of the button that should not be clicked anymore anyway), and you can show the response in the same place, or choose to show a notification (or both).

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  
  // Button is clicked. Disable and show an indicator.
  var button = $(this);
  button.prop('disabled', true);
  button.text('saving...');
  
  // Simulate the request that takes 5 seconds.
  setTimeout(
    function(){
      // Simulate success
      button.text('Saved!');
      button.css('color', 'green');
    }, 5000);
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>John <button>Send friend request</button>
<li>Jane <button>Send friend request</button>
<li>Jack <button>Send friend request</button>
<li>Janet <button>Send friend request</button>
```

Comment: wow! I can't believe how your answer @GolezTrol got here! I'll make sure I really digest it but it sounds like a smart move (I was too much trying to solve it on the PHP side). My only issue with it is that if the user then clicks on a link to another page, that would break the connection and the ajax request, correct?

Comment: It would break the request, so it is not waiting for the response, but you can make PHP finish the request by using [ignore_user_abort(true)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php). I've added a small heading about this to the answer.

Comment: Awesome! I just made a dummy test and it works like a charm! I also added a speicif error handling to ajax testing that xhr.status != 0 to avoid getting an error message when navigating away. Thanks again! :) (don't have enough reputation to upvote....)